# django object get/set field

Tags: django-models

Can I get the value of an object field some other way than `obj.field`? Does something like `obj.get('field')` exist? Same thing for setting the value of the field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to introspect django model fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384436/how-to-introspect-django-model-fields)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To get the value of a field:

```
getattr(obj, 'field_name')
```

To set the value of a field:

```
setattr(obj, 'field_name', 'field value')
```

To get all the fields and values for a Django object:

```
[(field.name, getattr(obj,field.name)) for field in obj._meta.fields]
```

You can read the documentation of [Model _meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/) which is really useful.

Comment: or, to update '''obj''' with items from a dictionary: [setattr(obj, key, value) for (key, value) in dictionary.items()]

Answer (score 6):

why do you want this?

You could use

```
obj.__dict__['field']
```

i guess... though it's not a method call

```
changed=[field for (field,value) in newObj.__dict__ if oldObj.__dict__[field] != value]
```

will give you a list of all the fields that where changed.

(though I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: after submitting an edit form for that object I have:

oldObj = ObjModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
newObj = editForm.save(commit = False)

and I want to compare the two objects, I need to know which fields were changed by the edit form. Is there any way easier way of doing that, except comparing the objects field by field?

Comment: Doesn't always work (foreign keys break this). Use @João Marcus answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody stumbles upon this little question, the answer is right here:
[How to introspect django model fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384436/how-to-introspect-django-model-fields)

Answer (score 2):

To get related fields:

```
def getattr_related(obj, fields):
    a = getattr(obj, fields.pop(0))
    if not len(fields): return a
    else:               return getattr_related(a, fields)
```

E.g.,

```
getattr_related(a, "some__field".split("__"))
```

Dunno, perhaps there's a better way to do it but that worked for me.