# How to create model containing subset of User model's fields in Django

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

How can I create `OrderUser` model containing subfields of `User` model that are desired:

- first_name
- last_name
- email

**I want to avoid manually copying fields' structure from django.contrib.auth.models AbstractUser** like

```
class OrderUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
```

I wonder if there is any way to write something like this:

```
class OrderUser(models.Model):
    first_name = User.fields.first_name
    last_name = User.fields.last_name
    email = User.fields.email
```

Usually, if I want two models to have the same fields, I use Abstract Model inheritance.
But inheriting from AbstractUser leads to many unnecessary fields like username, is_staff, is_active and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my bad, I finally found an answer to my own question, maybe it will be helpful for someone else.

The `_meta` property worked for me:

```
class OrderUser(models.Model):
    first_name = User._meta.get_field_by_name('first_name')[0]
    last_name = User._meta.get_field_by_name('last_name')[0]
    email = User._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]
```

More discussion about `_meta`:

- [Get model's fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/get-models-fields-in-django)
- [How to introspect django model fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384436/how-to-introspect-django-model-fields)