# Get an attribute's class from its name in Python?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I get class attribute's type in Python the same way I do it in Java with this code?

```
Field f = ClassName.class.getDeclaredField("attr_name");
Class<?> ftype = f.getType();
```

With

```
c = ClassName()
c.__dict__
```

I can get all attributes name and values, but not their types.

More specifically, using Django, if I have two classes, say Poll and Choice, defined as follow

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How can I know if a class has a `models.ForeignKey` as attribute's type and to which other class it points?

I need as output something like:

```
# attribute poll in class Choice is a ForeignKey type
# and it points to Poll model
Choice.poll -> Poll
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the class name of a related model, use `rel.to`:

```
print Choice.poll.field.rel.to.__name__   # prints 'Poll'
```

Or, this way:

```
field = Choice._meta.get_field_by_name('poll')[0]
print field.rel.to.__name__  # prints 'Poll'
```

Also see:

- [How to introspect django model fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384436/how-to-introspect-django-model-fields)

Answer (score 3):

To get the type of an object in Python, use `type`. From there, you can use `__name__` to get the name of the class as a string:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     pass
...
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> type(obj)
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> type(obj).__name__
'MyClass'
```

Comment: Might also add that `type(obj).__name__` will render its name.