# String Dictionary Representation of a Model/Object instance in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, model, representation

I feel that this is a very simple question, but I'm new to Python, and I'm learning Django at the same time.

My objective is to create a string dictionary representation i.e. it's dictionary formatted but a string, of a Model's instance in Django. How could I do that? Is there a built-in function that I can call straight from the object's instance, or do I have to define one?

**UPDATE:**

I would like to call this functionality within the model definition itself i.e. I'm implementing a class method or function which needs this functionality. I'm thinking of a functionality which behaves like python's built-in function `locals()` but should only return the model's attributes.

I also would like to add that I'll be calling this functionality on a model's instance which has not been saved yet to the database. So in essence, I'll be working on a model's instance representing a record which is not yet in the database. So anything function using a `Manager or QuerySet` I guess is not why I'm looking for.

Example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
     name = ...
     age =  ...

     def func_doing_something(self):
          #get the string dictionary representation of this model's instance
          #do something to it
          #return something
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019885/191064) the solution I was looking for...

some Django object `obj`

```
[(field.name, getattr(obj,field.name)) for field in obj._meta.fields]
```

and just call `dict()` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use p = Person(name='john', age=10).values()

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

To get it to a string use:

```
s = str(p[0])
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, but that's just the first part of what I'm trying to. I want to store the that dictionary into the database, so I'm thinking I'm gonna need to convert it to a string first. Is there other way to do this? How can I turn the dictionary representation into a string? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why would you want to store the string representation in the db? That makes no sense.

Comment: let's say I want to call another function with that string as an argument, and I need it to be a string because that function will process it as a string. :)

Comment: oh, that was easy. thank you very much! I feel so dumb right now. Hahaha really,

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I have to unaccept your answer. I just realised this is not a solution to the case I'm trying to solve. Basically, I'll be working on a single instance of a model at a time, not q QuerySet, so it does not work. I would like to get the string dictionary representation of a model instance i.e. object, within the model definition itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your objects to json format, e.g. with django build-in [serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2) 
This allows you deserialize quite easily.

Comment: I read that a serializer expects a QuerySet as an argument. In my case, I'll be working on a single instance of a model at a time before it is even saved into the database. Thank you!